# Can we have a series of functions which does not converge uniformly, but is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

Can we have a series of functions which does not converge uniformly, but is differentiable? Usually uniform convergence does not imply differentiability, so functions like Weierstrass function is uniformly convergent but is not differentiable. Can we have the opposite?

Comment: You have to assume some regularity of the functions to make sense of this question, there's also no reason to consider series instead of sequences. Also, almost any standard example (like $e^x$) should answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Take $$\sum x^n $$

its sum $x\mapsto \frac {1}{1-x} $ is differentiable at $[0,1) $ but the series does not converge uniformly at $[0,1) $.

$$\sup_{x\in [0,1)} |\frac {x^{n+1}}{1-x}|=+\infty $$